# My rhydon has increased CP for no apparent reason

Tags: pokemon-go

My rhydon was almost 1300 CP as of last night and I haven't played since. When I turned on the game about a half hour ago, it was at almost 2000 CP. I still have the same amount of stardust and candy. I don't know what happened. Can someone fill me in on how this happened?

Answer (score 1):

There was a re-balancing update recently. You can read the announcement [here](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/cp_update/) which is dated November 21st, 2016. I've quoted the announcement below.

> **Adjustments to the Combat Power of Various Pokémon**
>
> Trainers,
>
> We have made adjustments to the CP (Combat Power) of various Pokémon. Some Pokémon, such as Alakazam, Rhydon, and Gengar will have their CP increased. Others will have their CP lowered. These changes will allow a more balanced and competitive battling and training experience in Gyms. We will continue to adjust the CP going forward to improve the game balance when necessary.
>
> **The Pokémon GO team**

Comment: Thank I conldnt find anything about it and 700 cp is a big jump for nothing and made curios but thanks again